# An application for website comments

Tags: hosted, github, comment-system, jekyll

I have a Jekyll-based blog hosted on GitHub Pages. I want a plugin or an API that would come as a script and allow people to add comments on a particular article.

My requirements are as follows:

- Support for Jekyll and GitHub Pages
- No pre-registration required
- No ads - I don't seek to earn money through my website

Any other good feature will be great, but I'm primarily looking for the above three.

Comment: As *Disqus* was suggested, see also the related question: [Free alternative to Disqus](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3439/60)

Comment: Would you want to host the comments?

Comment: @Rainb I don't remember where I would've wanted to do so back then . But since the blog is hosted on Github pages, you can assume no hosting server access. Which means, any free-ish solution works. I've seen (but not tried) some really wacky solutions involving Spreadsheets on Google Drive, Github Issues, CSVs on GitHub paste etc since then. At the moment, I use Disqus, just for the ease of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Disqus](http://disqus.com/). It's free, very easy to integrate into websites, and used by companies like CNN for their commenting systems.

I use Disqus on all of my Wordpress installations, two of my Ghost installations and one static website - each of which took less than ten minutes to set up.

One downside to Disqus is that it shows under a tab, "Around the Web" which is essentially similar articles to the one you're commenting on. I'm not sure if this can be turned off, but I'd expect it to be.

Disqus features nested discussions, upvoting and downvoting, anti-spam filters and image & video embedding.

One of the coolest extensions I've seen for Disqus (which doesn't natively support extensions, I should add) is an embed-hack called [inlineDisqussions](http://tsi.github.io/inlineDisqussions/), which provides inline comments *a la* Medium.com.

Answer (score 1):

Seems [Talkyard blog comments](https://www.talkyard.io/blog-comments) can be useful to you. It's open source, and there's serverless hosting, with privacy — no ads, no tracking.

Here're instructions for Jekyll: https://jekyll-demo.talkyard.io/2018/01/09/installation-instructions.html

There's Gmail and Facebook login, and optional anonymous guest login (is that what you meant with no pre-registration?). There're upvotes, best comments shown first, a Disagree vote, images and videos. — I'm developing Talkyard. Screenshot:

[image: A screenshot of a discussion, 3 people talking]