# Free alternative to Disqus

Tags: open-source, hosted, comment-system

I am looking for a free as in freedom alternative to [Disqus](http://disqus.com/). Disqus is a third-party comment system for any website.

Feature requested:

- Shouldn't require me to host it
- Integrate on any page in my website
- Be free as in freedom

It would be preferable that:

- It would be easy to use
- It be coded in an exotic language (i.e. no Python, no PHP, no Node.js)
- I could choose where to store comments
- It includes a sophisticated up/downvote system

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "exotic?"  Are you referring to a Domain-Specific Language?

Comment: [This](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MostExoticRealProgrammingLanguage) kind of thing. I agree it might be a bit subjective, but as it is only some side-requirement, I decided to keep it.

Comment: That seems like kind of a [specious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) software requirement.

Comment: TSC is way worse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org)?
[image]

I'm a touch biased, as it was created by our co-founder Coding Horror, (without whom I'd probably still be working as a finance exec, grinding orphans into money burgers for the rich to feed their pets,) but it seems to nail most of your criteria:

- It's open-source
- They offer (paid) hosting if you don't want to do it yourself
- It's a JavaScript application that runs in your web browser, using the Ember.js JavaScript framework.  The server side of Discourse is written in Ruby on Rails with a Postgres database, and Redis server cache.

At a glance, it looks more like a tool for stand-alone discussion forums, but seems to also be a much improved way to discuss "parent" pieces of content, instead of other commenting systems - that's just [what boingboing did.](http://boingboing.net/2013/06/27/can-we-talk.html)

Comment: Ruby on rails - that's a fun language :). I'll give it a try.

Comment: What about a voting system tho? And I get a "kindle" icon following me on every page on boingboing, is it linked to discourse? I would hate this.

Comment: @VicAche, I think discourse has a "top posts" feature where the most "starred" posts in a dialogue are displayed at the top, but it's not a pure, fully-integrated vote-ranking.  I'm not sure about that kindle thing, but I'd be *very* surprised if it were a mandatory component of Discourses; I suspect it's a boingboing choice.

Comment: OK. My main concern with isso is the poor voting system, it's easier to delete/edit a post than to come back on a cast vote, and it seems that Discourse isn't really doing better.

Comment: This feels like more of a reframing of the question, than an answer for it. I get that BoingBoing talked up their then-recent switch from Disqus to Discourse forums as if that was somehow a new idea. Even though Ars Technica, for one, have operated their article comments like that since time immemorial — except at Ars, the comment posts hosted in each article's discussion forum are _also_ integrated directly into the article page as on-site comments. BoingBoing claimed that "At Boing Boing itself, the best comments will often appear under the posts" which is hardly the same thing at all.

Answer (score 5):

An interesting alternative I found is [isso](http://posativ.org/isso/).

- It can be hosted away from my static pages
- It integrates well
- It is free as in freedom.

As for the other requirements:

- It is pretty easy to use
- It is coded in a well-known language, Python, which is a bit boring - not fine
- It stores comments in a sqlite database by default - not fine
- It does include a voting system, but votes cannot be updated even after comments are edited.

Answer (score 2):

[Talkyard](https://www.talkyard.io/blog-comments) is a new alternative this year 2018. It's similar to Disqus: threaded, and best comments shown first.

Your requested features:

- *Shouldn't require me to host it*: **Yes, fine.** There's serverless hosting, see the link above. (It costs money.)
- *Free as in freedom*: **Yes**, Talkyard is free and [open source](https://github.com/debiki/talkyard) under the AGPL licence; you can install on your own server.
- *Integrate on any page in my website*: **Yes.** Copy-paste a bit `<html>` into your page (or page templates). Or follow the instructions for Jekyll, Hugo or Gatsby.

Other features:

- *Easy to use*: I think the hosted serverless version is easy to use. If, though, you want to install yourself, then you need to get a server, sign up for some send-email-service, configure Google and Facebook OpenAuth login apps, configure DNS settings, which takes some time. This is not specific to Talkyard though.
- *An exotic language*: Why? :- ) Anyway, it's written in Scala and React.js.
- *I could choose where to store comments*: The comments are stored in a PostreSQL database.
- *Up/downvote system*: Yes. Best comments shown first, as with Disqus. And you can see what stuff people *disagree* about.

I'm developing Talkyard. Screenshot:

[image]

*Bonus feature:* Talkyard is [community software](https://www.talkyard.io) too. You can create a discussion forum at `forum.yourwebsite.com` with StackExchange question-answers features, and Slack like chat features, that integrates with the embedded comments.